# Debugging React app works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, source-maps

I have a small React app deployed on Heroku as described [here](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration).

When I run the app locally with `npm start` I can use Google Chrome's debugger pane to view the source of App.js, set breakpoints and use the debugger to step through the source code of my app successfully.  So far so good!

When I try to repeat this with the same code deployed on Heroku, Chrome's view of App.js changes to show different source lines as being eligible for breakpoints.  (See the two side-by-side screenshots below.  Note that the line numbers greyed out on the left margin indicating ones ineligible for breakpoints are different.)  On Heroku, attempting to step through code in the debugger show the execution point jumping around wildly.  Sometimes lines do work for setting breakpoints, but many do not.

**What's going on here?  Is this a problem with the source maps?**  I'm a relative newby at React, so I don't know where to start investigating.

[image]

Comment: did you ever get this solved?

Comment: Sadly,  no.  My project continues to work inconsistently when deployed to the server and fine when debugged locally.

Comment: I ended up getting mine to work. I didn't have an index route, but was navigating there. Have you tried removing your Redirect call within your Switch statement.